# How can i prevent the user from running other applications programmatically in android?

Tags: android

I want to prevent the user from running some specific apps programmatically in Android? Kindly give some detailed answer if you know.

Comment: You can't do such a thing

Comment: I don't think you'll have permissions to do that. Maybe if device is rooted you can access to other apps processes, but I'm not sure if it would work.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a PID using a apps package name. with the pid you can close the app  like `android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);`If you put this logic in a loop you can close specific apps whenever they are opened. Not the same as preventing them from opening but in many cases will yield the same result.

```
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> pids = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
                     int processid = 0;
               for(int i = 0; i < pids.size(); i++)
               {
                   ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info = pids.get(i);
                   if(info.processName.equalsIgnoreCase("here your package name")){
                        android.os.Process.killProcess(info.pid);

                   } 
               }
```

Comment: Nice idea but some processes will automatically be restarted.

Comment: Well, that's what you have to do. I think the only way to prevent a process from ever starting is to remove it completely. And if its in a loop it shouldn't really be able to fully start up anyway, right?

Comment: Theyouthis .give some Coding details